# gvnix dynamic configuation addon with custom .properties files

Tags: spring-roo, gvnix

I'm using addon-dynamic-configuration from gvNIX 1.4.1 and I noticed that it works with some standard configuration files (database, log4j) but not with a custom .properties files.

From roo shell I type:
configuration property add --name [CTRL+Space] I see that the help propouses some properties. None of the properties I have defined in my custom file is listed.

Also if I execute:

```
configuration property add --name app.property1
```

I get the following error:

```
Property not exists
```

Is there any way to use this addon with customized properties files?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic config addon provides you an utility to manage project properties for several build profiles, for example on Maven projects these properties will be at pom.xml file.

To learn more read the reference guide for 1.4.1 at http://www.gvnix.org/en/, note that currently gvNIX ref guide is spanish only.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I read the document (I'm from Argentina, so spanish is perfect for me). I used multiple profiles and that's an excellent feature.

Comment: Problem is that the addon works only for some of the config files that are standard on the project. I can not manage parameters in my own defined properties files. I consider this tool very helpful because how it works, and how easy you can manage properties, but if I can not use it with my own files I will need to change dynamic-properties.xml by hand.